# É possível integrar um windows builder no Xamarin para o Mac?

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin, window-builder

Atualmente estou a usar um Mac, mas gostaria de continuar a usar o C# e criar novas `GUIs`, visto que não criei lá muita coisa. Então andei a procura duma solução para usar o C# para o Mac, e descobri o `Mono` framework, que é compatível com o famoso .NET framework da Microsoft.

Gostaria de criar GUIs usando um windows designer ou builder, como aquele no Visual Studio para o C#, ou aquele plug-in para o Eclipse `Window Builder` para Java.

Já ouvi falar que não existe integrado um Window Builder no Xamarin (MonoDevelop) para o Mac, mas existe uma possibilidade talvez  de instalar um?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri finalmente como usar o designer integrado no MonoDevelop (Xamarin é a versão que eu tenho para o OSX) para a criação de aplicações `Gtk#`(graças também a este post no SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224571/monodevelop-gtk-designer-just-shows-a-blank-square).

Para começar é preciso claro criar uma nova **solution**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu caso eu uso C#, portanto eu faço click em C#, e aparece-me ao lado direito a opção `Gtk# 2.0 Project`, e é mesmo essa que escolho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois aparece a tipica janela dum IDE, neste caso com o browser (da solução) a esquerda. Vai na pasta `User Interface`, e faça 2 clicks em `MainWindow`, em modo que se abra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vai te aparecer uma `Window` cinzenta (sem nada). Repara em baixo dela tem 2 "tabs": `Source` e `Designer`, se `Designer` não é selecionado, seleciona-lo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste momento, não deves ter, a direita, nenhuma toolbox que se chama `ToolBox`. No menu, vai em **View > Pads > Toolbox**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora a direita deveria aparecer-te a **Toolbox**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora estamos prontos para prosseguir com a parte mais fácil ;)